# Доставать вопросами. Можно ли так сказать?

Tags: стилистика

Можно ли так сказать: "Журналисты доставали вопросами"?

Answer (score 2):

"Доставать" в предполагаемом значении — распространённый жаргон. Поэтому сказать так, конечно, можно, но только если подобный жаргон уместен в том кругу, в котором Вы хотите это сказать.